# PHP - Get Classes public variables?

Tags: php, oop

Please consider the code below.

```
class A {
  public function __construct() {

  }
}

class B extends A {
  public $a = "a";
  public $b = "b";
  public $c = "c";
}
```

How do I get the class B's public variables from within the parent class without knowing precisely what they are?

Comment: Err, you can't? Unless you pass a reference of class B to A, or something.

Comment: This is not the OOP is meant to be, but there should be some workarounds..

Comment: Actually a parent class should not know about its inherited implementations. Maybe inheritance is not the right strategy here. Have a look at composition or the template pattern.

Answer (score 9):

```
class A {
   public $d;
   public function __construct() {
      $reflect = new ReflectionClass($this);
      $props = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
      var_dump($props);
   }
}

class B extends A {
  public $a = "a";
  private $b = "b";
  public $c = "c";
}
new B();
```

Output (notice no 'b', but A's public 'd' is in there, with a mention it's declared in A):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &object(ReflectionProperty)#3 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["class"]=>
    string(1) "B"
  }
  [1]=>
  &object(ReflectionProperty)#4 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "c"
    ["class"]=>
    string(1) "B"
  }
  [2]=>
  &object(ReflectionProperty)#5 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "d"
    ["class"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In A create an instance of B and then use

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Anyways, what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {        
    public function __construct() {   
        $array = get_class_vars('B'); // public vars of class B
   }
}

class B extends A {    
    public $a = "a";
    public $b = "b";
    public $c = "c";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the the B-Class-Object into the A-Class-Object:

```
class A {
    public $b;

    public function __construct(B $b_object) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

class B {
  public $a = "a";
  public $b = "b";
  public $c = "c";
}
```

So the constructor waits for a Objekt of B here. And now let's use it.

```
$b = new B();
$a = new A($b);

$a->b->a;
$a->b->b;
$a->b->c
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't see that class B extends class A. So just forget about my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

A subclass *inherits* from the superclass. Just as a father doesn't inherit any genes from his daughter, only gives them, this isn't possible. Well, technically it is, but it isn't the correct way of implementing object-oriented behavior.

I recommend giving the variable to the superclass, that way it is accessible by both classes, although I'm unsure what you're using it for.

Hope that helps!