# loop through all public variables and translate NULL values to empty strings

Tags: php

How to loop through all public variables in a class from inside the class?

How to get the public variables?

```
private function translate_null_values_to_strings(){
    foreach($this->public_vars as $key => $value){
        if(is_null($this->$key)) $this->$key = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309320/php-get-classes-public-variables

Comment: [`ReflectionClass::getProperties`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)`(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC)`

Comment: I would avoid doing this.. there's something wrong in your app if the object have some properties set with values you don't want later..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Reflection](http://br.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). I've modified an example from the PHP manual to get what you want:

```
class Test
{
    public $public1 = 'public 1';
    public $public2 = '';
    public $public3 = 'public 3';
    private $private1 = 'private 1';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $reflect = new ReflectionObject($this);
        foreach ($reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $prop)
        {
            $propName = $prop->getName();
            echo $propName." --> ". $this->$propName . "\n";
        }
    }
}

$ob = new Test();
```

**Output:**

```
public1 --> public 1
public2 --> 
public3 --> public 3
```